# How to monitor onprem sql server in azure

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-log-analytics

I would like to monitor the databases that are active and high availability status of my on-prem SQL server which is in azure VM.

Comment: How can your on-prem SQL Server be in an Azure VM?

Comment: @Priyanka : You need to rephrase the question. Do you want to monitor the SQL Server hosted on Azure VM ? Then the answer will be you can monitor them like you monitor any on prem server with the same set of tools like SCOM , Solar winds , Idera. Also if you are lookin in to azure monitor with Log analytics it has a SQL Server Assesment solution as well you cn configure few alerts of your own as well.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Arun's comment / suggestion i.e., to go for Azure Monitor, SQL Server Assessment solution, Alerts; I would recommend you to go for Azure SQL Analytics solution and SQL Health Check solutions as well for even better monitoring. For more information w.r.t it, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/azure-sql) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/sql-assessment) documents. Hope this helps!